# Spacing of UI Elements based on Screen Size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

The initial screen of my app prompts the user to enter in their schedule, I have implemented constraints, however on small screen sizes like the iPhone SE, the Text Fields and Switches are too far apart and as a result the size of the label above is decreased and an entire row (Text Field + Switch) is cut off. On devices with larger screen sizes like the iPhone 8 plus, their is space at the bottom. How would change the spacing of the rows based on the screen size of the device to insure that all of the UI elements are displayed properly? Essentially, I would like each phone size to display something similar the iPhone 8 where their is a small amount of space at the bottom of the display.

**Iphone 8 plus**
[image: iPhone 8 Plus]

**iPhone 8**
[image: iphone 8]

**iPhone SE**
[image: iPhone SE]**

Comment: Have you tried giving the UILabels a height constraint? Also, for something like this, I would recommend that you use a UITableView https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview?changes=_6

Comment: @GabrielPires Currently I am using a height constraint with an Equal relation for the space in between the UISwitches, UILabels and UITextfields. I have looked into using a table view for this but I prefer how my current implementation (when displayed properly) looks.

Comment: oh that's odd. Then shouldn't the height of "Period 2" be equal to the height of "Period 3"? Could you log out the heights of both? Or make the background color of the labels blue?

Comment: adding your uiview to scrollView will give you space as you need when there is no space left in bottom. and give your constraint from top to bottom will fix that cut off.

Comment: @GabrielPires All of the Labels that display the Period number have a height of 20.

Comment: @GovindKumawat Is their a way display the constraints on a view controller in a formatted way, currently [this](https://imgur.com/a/7C0vuTc) is how they show up in the side bar, and I would assume this isn't much of a help.

Comment: Change spacing of UI Elements is not good solution. If you change spacing you should change both height of Elements -> too complex
Try embed all Elements in UIScrollview.

Comment: @Lontronix it's better you implement each schedule inside `UIView` so for one View per schedule then it's more each to track what's going on instead adding `constraint` in main `superView` but this a wrong approach when you have similar view more then 2 or 3 time always go for `UITableView` or `CollectionView` as per your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in many ways. The first thought that came to my mind is...
Group or Embed the Period Label, text field and the switch into a UIView.

[image: Period Group]

Do this for all 8 periods. Then insert these 8 UIViews into UIStackView - vertical with equal spacing. Now add constraints to the UIStackview with standard leading and trailing spaces, add standard margin from the top and your defined margin from the bottom. This will give you similar looks on all screen sizes.